# Dynamic selectees not working in JQuery-UI selectable

Tags: jquery-ui, selectable, jquery-ui-selectable

I am crating a windows like interface where I have a canvas and into it I can append multiple icons dynamically. I have set the canvas to selectable.
The problem is that when I add new icons, I can't select them.

I tried adding ui-selectee class to the icon but it doesn't work either.

```
$('.canvas').selectable({ 
   filter: $('.icons'),
   autoRefresh: true,  
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add param 'cancel':

```
$('.canvas').selectable({ 
   filter: $('.icons'),
   cancel: 'a',
   autoRefresh: true,  
});
```

Or delay param, his helps prevent unwanted selections when clicking on an element.
http://api.jqueryui.com/1.8/selectable/